# What is the .NET Core equivalent of IAuthenticationFilter?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, action-filter

How can authentication be done in .NET Core as it was done using IAuthenticationFilter?

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthenticationFilter  
{  
    void IAuthenticationFilter.OnAuthentication(AuthenticationContext filterContext)  
    {  
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(filterContext.HttpContext.Session["Username"])))  
        {  
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();  
        }  
    }  

    void IAuthenticationFilter.OnAuthenticationChallenge(AuthenticationChallengeContext filterContext)  
    {  
        if (filterContext.Result == null || filterContext.Result is HttpUnauthorizedResult)  
        {  
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(  
                new RouteValueDictionary {  
                { "controller", "Account" },  
                { "action", "Login" } });  
        }  
    }  
}
```

I am a newbie with .NET Core and filters. I was trying to authenticate users with filters before they can be allowed to access an action in a controller. Using this in .NET Core gives an error

"Error  CS7069  Reference to type 'HttpContextBase' claims it is defined in 'System.Web', but it could not be found".

After searching this error I found that this is only available in .NET Framework. How do I do authentication with filters in .NET Core?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters

Comment: Asp.net core doesn't contain the IAuthenticationFilter, if you want to authencated the user, I suggest you could try to refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple?view=aspnetcore-6.0#authorize-attribute-and-razor-pages). If you want to check the user's claim before go to the controller, you could consider using the IAuthorizationFilter.

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net core doesn't contain the IAuthenticationFilter, if you want to authenticated the user, I suggest you could try to refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple?view=aspnetcore-6.0#authorize-attribute-and-razor-pages).

If you want to check the user's claim like roles before go to the controller, you could consider using the IAuthorizationFilter.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
public class CustomAuthorizationFilterAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        string currentUserRole = Convert.ToString(context.HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserRole"));

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentUserRole))
        {
            if (currentUserRole != "Admin")
            {
                context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult
            (
            new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                action = "Error",
                controller = "Error"
            }));

            }
            else
            {
                context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult
           (
           new RouteValueDictionary(new
           {
               action = "Error",
               controller = "Error"
           }));

            }
        }
        else
        {
            context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult
            (
            new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                action = "Error",
                controller = "Error"
            }));

        }
    }
}
```